# connect mvc3 membership with sql database

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the built-in membership for mvc3 with an online sql database, so I changed my connection string to look like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ApplicationServices" 
        connectionString="Data Source=72.18.142.170,1533;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=entertainment;User Id=uname;Password=pswd;"  
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But when I try to register a new user I get the following error:

> {"Invalid object name
>   'dbo.aspnet_SchemaVersions'."}    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Thank you for your help

Comment: That database appears to be connectable from the internet.  Are you sure that's intentional?

Answer (score 1):

The table `aspnet_SchemaVersions` doesn't exist in the database `entertainment` (or at least in the default schema).  (Conversely, I suppose it's possible that the user `uname` just doesn't have access to the table.)

You need to create the tables for the membership provider to use.

Comment: it does have access since i am using it to add/edit/delete fields in another table in the same db ... shouldnt the application to create the tables if they don't exist ?

Comment: @CharbelWakim: It has access to the database, but I believe access can also be specified at the schema and table levels.  _Should_ the application create the tables?  It's your application, you tell me.  I wouldn't expect it to by default.  Is there any logic in the application to create the tables?  If you profile the SQL server while the application tries to access it, does it make any attempt to see if the tables exist and/or create them?

Comment: yes i can create tables i did it before i have 6 tables created. The thing is it's not entirely my app i am covering for someone so i dont have all the aspect covered yet, anywayz if you are sure it is a permission issue i will check with the IT

Comment: @CharbelWakim: Well, it _might_ be a permission issue.  I can't be sure.  The error message indicates that the table doesn't exist.  So I'd first check if the table exists.

Comment: it turns out a compatibility issue between the local db and the online one ... so i had to generate sql 2005 script rather than 2008 ...