# Asp.Net MVC 4 Server error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, code-first, simplemembership

Mine is an Asp.Net MVC 4 application hosted on 1and1 server.

I use SimpleMembership provider with Asp.Net MVC 4 and codefirst approach with entity framework.

Everything works fine but I randomly get this error.

**I get this error only in 1and1 hosting - not in any other hosting and not even in my local machine**

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.aspnet_SchemaVersions'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.aspnet_SchemaVersions'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.aspnet_SchemaVersions'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1753986
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5296058
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +558
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +269
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +1379
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +175
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +205
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +160
   System.Web.Util.SecUtility.CheckSchemaVersion(ProviderBase provider, SqlConnection connection, String[] features, String version, Int32& schemaVersionCheck) +402
   System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.CheckSchemaVersion(SqlConnection connection) +64
   System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) +762
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) +54
   System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +9461104
   System.Func`2.Invoke(T arg) +0
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +160
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +445
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +302
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +338
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +316
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +71
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +251
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I am using role based security (Simple one default in framework 4.)

I have checked the database and the stored procedure is already there. Further, this error does not pop up each time but randomly.

Question:

Am I missing something ? Do I need further configuration ?
Why am I getting this error ?
Why it is random ?
Does using MVC 4 makes some difference ?

I have googled a lot on it and everyone suggest using aspnet_regsql utility to register db for forms authentication. I have checked it and everything generated by the wizard is in my db still I am getting this error.

Comment: have you taken a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900601/connect-mvc3-membership-with-sql-database

Comment: @G_P - Please go through the question again. I have already stated that all the tables and default schema is there in my db. Further, I am getting this error randomly where as the given answer is for one finite, reproducable error. I assume that the error is host specific.

Comment: ahh - sorry, I missed the random occurrence info. What does your conn. string look like?

Comment: <add name="sAContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=db11111111111.db.1and1.com;Initial Catalog=db11111111111;User ID=dbo12345678;Password=password;" />

Comment: I would check with the host. It sounds like they might be load balancing the database and one copy is out of date compared to the rest.

Comment: @MattDavies - I had no idea of such things done by the host. How do I confirm this theaory ?

Comment: I believe their support email is support@1and1.com. I'd indicate to them that it appears sometimes when you access your database tables are missing, other times they are there.

Comment: One more thing, I am using simplemembership available with Asp.net MVC 4 which does not require any stored procedure at all and I am using CodeFirst approach. Why it is still looking up for this stored procedure ?